# ¿Porque el addEventListener de javascript no reconoce funciones que están dentro de funciones?

Tags: javascript, funciones, eventos

Tengo el siguiente código:

```js
const boton1 = document.getElementById("boton");

function draw() {
  function saludar(){
    alert("hola")
  }
}

boton1.addEventListener("click", saludar)
```

```html
<button id="boton">Saludar</button>
```

La función saludar, que puse como parámetro, la puse dentro de otra función.

Me sale el error:

> `saludar is not defined`

La solución fue colocar la función `saludar` fuera de la función `draw`

La pregunta es ¿Porqué `addEventListener` no reconoce funciones dentro de otras funciones como en el ejemplo?

Comment: Es por el ámbito de la función. Léete https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#%C3%A1mbito_de_function

Comment: Porque la funcion saludar solo existe dentro de la funcion draw, no afuera... por eso afuera dice que no está definida